# serialization multiple objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to make an application that allows people to register their information so that employers could read them and contact them.

The problem is whenever I try to deserialize the information, I either get one object only, or the program throw an exception.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream sw = new FileStream("Applicants.xml",FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None);
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Class1), new XmlRootAttribute("Applist"));
    Class1 cc = new Class1();
    cc.name = textBox1.Text;
    cc.age = textBox2.Text;
    cc.degree = textBox3.Text;
    cc.salary = textBox4.Text;
    cc.no = textBox5.Text;
    c.Add(cc);

    xs.Serialize(sw,cc);


    this.Hide();
}
```

What should I do to serialize and deserialize all the objects created ? 
class1 :

```
public class Class1
{
    public String name;
    public String age;
    public String degree;
    public String no;
    public String salary;

}
```

deserialization code :

```
 private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked_1(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
 {
       List<Class1> c2 = new List<Class1>();
       XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Class1>));
       FileStream fs = new FileStream("Applicants.xml",FileMode.Open);
       c2 = (List<Class1>)xml.Deserialize(fs);
       label3.Text = ; //don't know what t write here 
 }
```

Comment: What is c ? List<Class1> ?

Comment: c is a list of class1 that contains fields (name,age,degree,salary)

Comment: it's seem that you serialize cc and not c. So you will get only cc, and not a list of c

Comment: if i serialize c , it throws an exception (error generating xml document )

Comment: You need to: 1. Show the full definition of `Class1`, 2. show the code you are using to deserialize the XML and 3. detail the exception that you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to serialize the list, you have to create the Serializer for the type of `List<Class1>`.

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Class1>), new XmlRootAttribute("Applist"));
```

And then serialize the actual list instead of `cc`.

```
xs.Serialize(sw,c);
```

Comment: that worked (Y) , but what about deserializtion , excuse me am still a beginner :'D

Comment: @MayarAkram: I am not sure what you want to show in the label3 Text. You have already managed to Deserialized it and got the list of Class1 instances. You can do what every you want from the list.

Comment: @MayarAkram: Please remember to select an answer for your question if there is any answer that solved your question.

Comment: I made label3.text to print all the serialized information again to show it all , but I can't

Comment: @MayarAkram: After deserializing you get a list of objects. You cannot show all objects in one label text.